# Any sample on how to expose a olap cube as oData so it can be used using powerpivot?

Tags: excel, odata, olap, cube, powerpivot

I'm looking for a sample on how to expose an olap cube as an odata feed so it can be consumed by powerpivot. I do not want to provide direct access to the cube.

Comment: got any answers ? Would like to know about how to create visualization off cubes in sharepoint

Comment: Filip, Where is the OLAP cube? What kind of server are you trying to access via odata?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SSAS cubes as OData feed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23558931/ssas-cubes-as-odata-feed)