# SSAS cubes as OData feed

Tags: .net, ssas, odata, olap

As Excel PowerPivot supports Odata feeds, I'm looking for some technical solution to expose SSAS cubes as OData feeds. Are there any known ways/frameworks of achieving this?

**EDIT:**

I need to be able to slice and dice data coming from the cubes through a client application (in this case Excel). OData feeds as a data source is a requirement as well. SSRS report exposed as OData is not an option, since it is rigid and has a consistent form.

Comment: An alternative can be to use my product [AdaptiveLINQ](http://www.adaptivelinq.com) directly on your OLTP model

Answer (score 0):

I would use Reporting Services (SSRS).

SSRS is fairly well integrated with SSAS, with a few quirks.

Once SSRS reports are published to a Report Manager or SharePoint portal, they can be used to generate an Atom-format Odata feed.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff519563.aspx

Comment: but what if I want to slice and dice the corresponding data? SSRS report is rigid and has a consistent form, so you can't achieve the latter.

Comment: But what if ... you listed your full requirements in your initial question?